# Error when using P3D Processing 3

Tags: processing

Could you please help me
I am trying to start drawing 3D shapes using Processing 3
Whenever the renderer P3D is used, I get the following Error

ERROR: 0:2: '' : Declaration must include a precision qualifier or the default precision must have been previously declared. 
ERROR: 0:30: '' : Declaration must include a precision qualifier or the default precision must have been previously declared.

The piece of code I am trying to run:

```java
    float x,y,z;
    void setup() {
      size(200,200,P3D);
      x = width/2;
      y = height/2;
      z = 0;
    }

    void draw() {
      translate(x,y,z);
      rectMode(CENTER);
      rect(0,0,100,100);

    z++; // The rectangle moves forward as z increments.
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: This code works fine for me using Processing 3 on Windows 10.

Comment: I have got it from a tutorial, and that what is driving me crazy. I am not able to find anything related to this error in the context of Processing.

Comment: It doesn't sound like a Processing error. Maybe an issue with OpenGL?

Comment: Maybe, but I have tried the same code in Processing 2 and every thing was fine.

Comment: Do you get a stack trace? Can you tell where in Processing this error is happening?

Comment: Whenever I use P3D

Comment: That's really not enough information to go on. You need to figure out exactly what is causing that error, possibly inside Processing itself. A stack trace would go a long way in figuring that out.